# Batch Checking Adobe AIR Version

Tags: air

I want to write a batch file which will check if Adobe AIR is installed in the system or not and if installed is it version 3.0 or newer version. If not installed or old version is installed then it will install  C:\AdobeAIRInstaller.exe

Comment: I hope someone is able to help you here, as I don't know your project specs. Just a heads up that may be useful in some cases...I think the Adobe AIR installer that you create from Flash Professional handles all of this already for you.

Comment: By the way, you may want to clarify your question here. Right now, it seems to be asking for the whole code, which I'm fairly sure wasn't your intent.

Comment: I want to do the same operations which the Adobe AIR Installer does but without starting it i.e. using batch as it will be fast and no need of user clicks to skip if AIR is already installed

Comment: Ah, okies. Just be sure to clarify your question to ensure you get an answer. (There needs to be an actual specific question above.)